# some_struct* args1 = (some_struct*)args2

Tags: c++

In this c++ code, could someone explain what the following line is doing, I have not seen this notation before.

```
some_struct* args1 = (some_struct*)args2
```

A simplified example is:

```
struct some_struct
{
 myClass1* thisClass1;
};

void function1(void *args2)
{
some_struct* args1 = (some_struct*)args2;
//do some more stuff
}
int Main(int argc, char* argv)
{
mainClass1=myClass1::new()
some_struct args2;
args2.thisClass1=mainClass1;
function1((void *)&args2);
return 0;
}
```

Forgive my grammar, I usually program in Python.

Comment: There are many more issues that you need to fix prior to this. If you're Python programmer, it shouldn't be hard to start using started subset of C++, just get a book and go through all examples carefully.

Comment: The line in `main` should be `function1(&args2)`

Comment: Thanks matt, i corrected the mistake in the example function1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function the variable `args2` is a generic pointer, meaning it can point to anything but you can't use it directly as there is no type information associated with `void`. The expression `(some_struct*)args2` tells the compiler to pretend that `args2` is a pointer to `some_struct`.

This type of expression is called a *cast expression*, as it "casts" one type as another type. The syntax is a C-style cast, which is inherited in C++ from it roots in the C language.

The C++-specific equivalent of a C-style cast is [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret%5fcast), like

```
some_struct* args1 = reinterpret_cast<some_struct*>(args2);
```

Comment: I think I've never heard `generic pointer` for `void pointer` before, but it sounds like a very good description for it.

Comment: `void *` was added to C89 for exactly that reason. Previously, people had been using `char *` as a generic pointer, which was a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

It casts `args2` to a `some_struct` pointer and then assigns that casted pointer to `args1`. This is needed, because the argument of `function1` is a void pointer, meaning no type information is associated with it. For some reason the programmer is sure that the argument of `function1` is of type `some_struct*` and therefore allows himself to do the cast.

*Sidenote:* Doing this is *really* bad style unless unavoidable.